# Match a bigger table with a smaller one with php and mysqli

Tags: php, sql, mysqli, while-loop

Most importantly! The focus of this question is the while loop at the end and the "result table" that follows.

First of all, the person 'Fredrik' is the one that's logged in in this example.

I have two tables in sql, "classes" and "bookings". "classes" shows all the available classes and when somebody books one of those the id of that specific class (id_classes) and the person's name ends up as a row in the table "bookings".

```
classes
id_class     date                    day            
1           2016-03-10 15:00:00     monday
2           2016-03-10 16:00:00     monday
3           2016-03-10 17:00:00     monday
4           2016-03-11 15:00:00     tuesday
5           2016-03-11 16:00:00     tuesday
6           2016-03-11 17:00:00     tuesday
7           2016-03-11 18:00:00     tuesday




bookings
    id      id_class    date                    day         name    
    1       2           2016-03-10 16:00:00     monday      Fredrik
    2       5           2016-03-11 16:00:00     tuesday     Richard
    3       7           2016-03-11 18:00:00     tuesday     Sara
    4       4           2016-03-11 15:00:00     tuesday     Fredrik
```

Then I want a php code that goes through the entire "classes" table and shows the logged in person (Fredrik) what classes that he's booked and what classes he hasn't booked. I've started with a simple while loop and some if statements. I need help to finish up this code. Additionally, both of these tables can be very big so efficiency advice are most welcome.

```
    <?php
        $result = $con->query("select * from classes");

        while(){

        if(){
            echo "Booked";

        }elseif(){
            echo "Not booked";

        }       

        }
<?
```

So what I was after all along is a resulting table that looks something like

```
result table
id_class     date                    day        status           
1           2016-03-10 15:00:00     monday      not booked
2           2016-03-10 16:00:00     monday      booked
3           2016-03-10 17:00:00     monday      not booked
4           2016-03-11 15:00:00     tuesday     booked
5           2016-03-11 16:00:00     tuesday     booked
6           2016-03-11 17:00:00     tuesday     not booked
7           2016-03-11 18:00:00     tuesday     booked
```

Answer (score -1):

First of all: Your information about the date and day of the class is redundant (the same information exists in the `classes` and `bookings` table). Remove that redundant information from the `bookings` table.

Then, use this SQL query for example (untested):

```
SELECT `c`.`date`, `c`.`day` FROM `bookings` AS `b` INNER JOIN `classes` AS `c` ON `b`.`id_class` = `c`.`id` WHERE `b`.`name` = '[loggedInUser]';
```

(Replace `[loggedInUser]` with your logged-in username, preferable with `PDO` prepared statements or at least escape it with `mysqli`!)

Comment: I've edited the question by adding a result table, which is the main goal of the question. I.e. a table that goes through all the available times in the "classes" table and tells if the user booked it or not.

Answer (score -1):

You dont need php to sort this out. You need a left join in this case.

```
SELECT a.id_class, a.date, a.day, b.booking_id, b.name FROM classes a LEFT JOIN bookings b ON a.idclass=b.id_class WHERE b.name="Frederick"
```

Comment: I've edited the question by adding a result table, which is the main goal of the question. I.e. a table that goes through all the available times in the "classes" table and tells if the user booked it or not.